# Docker xtb could not connect to display

Tags: qt, docker, qt5

Setup: Windows -> WSL Ubuntu -> Docker
The first time I've started a project, it worked correctly. Second time, it cannot find the display for an unknown reason, as the container is executed with XAuth passed, and even in privileged mode it fails.

Project: [Cutter docker dev build](https://github.com/radareorg/cutter/tree/master/docker)

```
qt.qpa.xcb: could not connect to display 
qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, xcb.
```